# Using hasManyThrough in Relationship query

Tags: php, laravel, relationship, eloquent

I have the following tables :

```
users
id|name|username

Areas
id|name

user_area
id|user_id|area_id

Buildings
id|name|area_id
```

In User models i want to call query that every users have his assigned areas and his assigned areas has many buildings, so i created a method in User model that query the user assigned buildings.
In App\User  Model:

```
 public function areas()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Area','area_user');
    }
  public function UserBuildings(){
        return $this>hasManyThrough('App\Building','App\Area','user_id','area_id');
    }
```

In App\Area Model:

```
public function users(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\User','area_user','area_id','user_id');
    }

    public function buildings(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Building');
    }
```

In App\Building Model:

```
public function areas(){
        $this->belongsTo('App\Area');
    }
```

How can i structure a relationship method in User Model that get the user assigned buildings.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can't use `hasManyThrough` here, but you can use nested `whereHas()` to get all buildings assigned to authenticated user:

```
Building::whereHas('area', function ($q) {
    $q->whereHas('users', function ($q) {
        $q->where('id', auth()->id());
    });
})->get();
```

Also, you should rename `areas` relationship to `area` in `Building` model, since each building belongs to only one area.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, i tried your above query in my Controller . Error showing:

Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalThrowableError (E_ERROR)
Call to a member function getRelationExistenceQuery() on null

=========================

Tried to figure where the problem, i noticed that when i query for area name of the specified building id , error showing :

>>> App\Building::find(1)->area
PHP error:  Trying to get property of non-object on line 1
>>>

Comment: @user2873860 this error is not related to this code.

Comment: When i removed the code , error disappeared. so i think it's related

Comment: @user2873860 if you're talking about relations error, you need to fix all relations. If you're talking about `Trying to get property of non-object` then it means there is no `Building` with ID = 1 and related to this code `App\Building::find(1)->area`

Comment: Yes, you are right, i don't have a building with id=1 , now i tried for building id = 24 

App\Building {#776
         id: 24,
         name: "Carpentry Workshop",
         symbol: "V",
         area_id: 6,
         building_type: 8,
         created_at: null,
         updated_at: null,
       },


but now it return null not the error :

 >>> App\Building::find(24)->area
=> null
    

And there is area with id = 6 in areas db table :

 App\Area {#759
         id: 6,
         name: "F",
         location_id: 3,
       
       },

Comment: I have fixed the relationship , now error showing, related to query you provided: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'id' in where clause is ambiguous (SQL: select * from `buildings` where exists (select * from `areas` where `buildings`.`area_id` = `areas`.`id` and exists (select * from `users` inner join `area_user` on `users`.`id` = `area_user`.`user_id` where `areas`.`id` = `area_user`.`area_id` and `id` = 11)))

Comment: @user2873860 my code can't cause this kind of error. Fix your relationships.

Comment: The error is exactly showing an sql query of eloquent query u provided, how it not related.